# how to capture image using expo-camera in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I am new to react-native. I have created an app. but now I want to Capture Image from this app. I have got the code from expo website But the problem is This code only open camera. I want to capture An Image Through That camera. So if it is possible please help me..

here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App({navigation}) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Ionicons style={{paddingLeft:20}} name="arrow-back" size={40} 
        color="black"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("OtherInfo")} />
        <Text style={{fontSize:20, paddingLeft: 70, paddingTop: 10}}>Get Image</Text>
      </View>

      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    camera:{
        height:500
    },
    header:{
      flexDirection: 'row'
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the working Example of the small app which takes the picture from Camera as well as Gallary and shows it to after it is clicked or selected

**Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/camera-permission)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add({ navigation }) {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
      presentationStyle: 0
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImageUri(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
          style={styles.fixedRatio}
          type={type}
          ratio={'1:1'}
        />
      </View>

      <Button title={'Take Picture'} onPress={takePicture} />
      <Button title={'Gallery'} onPress={pickImage} />
      {imageUri && <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: One more question. Can I remove that cropping image option from gallery images I mean can I select full image from gallery without croping it

Comment: You can, Just remove the aspect ratio option from ```pickImage``` function.

Comment: Ok Thanku Its Worked. One More I want to save 3 images in my app. So how could I do that . I have created a separate page for that. and now I want that when user click on Take picture button Then Images will be saved in that screen in small small ration. please. if you dont mind

Comment: just make a state which stores an array of images, and when the pickImage is ran, add the newly selected image in that array(state). Simple.

Comment: Ok I will try Thanks>>

Comment: If You Are free Now Can You Edit Above Code For that Please if You dont mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228146/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-sohil-shaikh).

Comment: please check it => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009837/how-to-captured-and-then-save-those-images-in-react-native-app-it-self

Comment: posted the answer with upadated code. do check out.